# What is the proper format to specify only new items with eBay's API?

Tags: javascript, ebay-api

I'm using the url format to parse eBays database, and I can't seem to figure out the correct way to filter items for a specific condition, as the condition histogram instructions aren't very clear. My current code is below.

```
<script src=http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=*APIKEY GOES HERE*&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest&itemFilter(0).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(0).value=500.00&itemFilter(0).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(0).paramValue=USD&itemFilter(1).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(1).value=200.00&itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter.name=ListingType&itemFilter.value=FixedPrice&itemFilter(1).paramValue=USD&keywords=iphone%205%2016gb%20unlocked&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=6>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Item Filter Type](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/types/ItemFilterType.html) in the **Ebay API.**  It has an **Enumeration Value** of **Condition** which has an **Allowed Text Value** of **New.**